# Java: how to open one Jframe from another Jframe which is not in the same file but in the same package;

Tags: java, netbeans

Java: how to open one Jframe from another Jframe which is not in the same file but in the same package;   For eg: project package is test1 and it has 2 Jframes ( home1 and home2 ) Need to open that second frame from the first one (home2 from home1) while clicking on a JButton called 'NEXT'.
can anyone help..

Comment: The same way you opened the first one: by creating an instance of it, and calling setVisible(true). We could help you with the code if you posted it. Since you didn't, all we can say is: read the swing tutorial.

Comment: `JFrame t1 = new test1.home1(); t1.setVisible(true)`;

Comment: ThankYou... yes... it worked with this simple code : JFrame t1 = new test1.home1(); t1.setVisible(true);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your problem is to open a new frame from a departure frame ? It's simple you just need to instanciate a new frame object like in the following :

```
JFrame home2 = new Home2(); // don't forget the import since it's a custom made Frame ;)
home2.setVisible(true);
```

Now you want that to be done when you click on a JButton. To do so you need to add an ActionListener, using an anonyous class, to the JButton with the previous code.

```
jb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            //stuff
        }
    });
```

See the addActionListener() method of [JButton](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html) and the [ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can show the other JFrame simply by calling

```
home2 h2 = new home2();
h2.setVisible(true);
```